# I have the cell displayed but I want the image to be displayed in the collection view cell when i press the button

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I want to insert images from array when I press the button

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        return cell
    }




    func buttonCreateStickerPressed(sender: UIButton!){
        let stickerName = "Sticker Number "+String(stickerDictionary.count+1)
        let stickerNumber = stickerDictionary.count+1
        makeSticker(stickerName, stickerNumber: stickerNumber)
        // let count = stickerArray.count



    }
```

Comment: I want to insert images from array when I press the button

Answer (score 0):

You can try reloadData and then set the image or if it should be done only for some indexes you can try reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes and then also set image in selected rows